# using pandas to extract the data I need

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a xlsx file that looks something like this;

```
Name     01/09/16        02/09/16          03/09/16       
Jack        In            Out                 In          
Lisa        Out           In                  Out             
Tom         Out           In                  In
```

I'm trying to print this data out in a table like the following using pandas;

```
+----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|               Status             |  01/09/16   |  02/09/16   |    03/09/16 |
+----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|               In                 |  Jack          Tom             Tom
                                                 |  Lisa       |    Jack     |
+----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|               Out                |  Lisa
                                      Tom        |  Jack       |    Lisa     |
+----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I'm struggling to find a way to do this with Pandas. I wanted to ask if there's any simple way to iterate down the dates column, match it to a row and get the cell value?

For example let's take the first column 01/09/16, how can I use pandas to go down that column and find the cell value 'In', match it with the row name 'Jack' and then add this to a nested dictionary like this;

```
dictionary = {'01/09/16': {In: [Jack], Out: [Lisa, Tom] } }
```

If I can get it like that, I can organize it in a table using something like PrettyTable like it shows in the second table above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a dictionary comprehension running across all series columns of dataframe. But first, make sure you make the *Name* the index of dataframe:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''
Name     01/09/16        02/09/16          03/09/16       
Jack        In            Out                 In          
Lisa        Out           In                  Out             
Tom         Out           In                  In
'''
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\s+", index_col=0)
print(df)

#      01/09/16 02/09/16 03/09/16
# Name                           
# Jack       In      Out       In
# Lisa      Out       In      Out
# Tom       Out       In       In

# BUILD DICTIONARY
dfdict = {col: (df[col][df[col] == 'In'].index.values,
                df[col][df[col] == 'Out'].index.values) for col in df.columns}
dfdict['Status'] = ['In', 'Out']

# CAST TO DATAFRAME 
finaldf = pd.DataFrame(dfdict)
finaldf = finaldf[['Status'] + [col for col in df.columns]]             # RE-ORDER COLS
print(finaldf)

#   Status     01/09/16     02/09/16     03/09/16
# 0     In       [Jack]  [Lisa, Tom]  [Jack, Tom]
# 1    Out  [Lisa, Tom]       [Jack]       [Lisa]
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
pd.melt(
    df, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=df.columns[1:].tolist(),
    value_name='Status', var_name='Date'
).set_index(['Status', 'Date']).groupby(level=[0, 1]).Name.apply(list).unstack()
```

[image]

Or with less code

```
df.set_index('Name').unstack().reset_index().groupby(['level_0', 0]) \
    .Name.apply(list).rename_axis([None, None]).unstack(0)
```

[image]

Comment: You was faster ;)